# multiple sql queries running issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am pretty new to PHP, and my current issue is with have to sql queries running on the same page.

I have two different divs on the same page. One div showing all jokes from of a store procedure, and the other one for the authors from a simple select.

What I get from this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever
>   going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.' in
>   /usr/local/pem/vhosts/272348/webspace/httpdocs/icloudis.com/sohail/crud_cssgrids/aeroplane.php:18
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /usr/local/pem/vhosts/272348/webspace/httpdocs/icloudis.com/sohail/crud_cssgrids/aeroplane.php(18):
>   PDO->query('select * from p...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /usr/local/pem/vhosts/272348/webspace/httpdocs/icloudis.com/sohail/crud_cssgrids/aeroplane.php
>   on line 18

I understand that from this message that I can't have several unbuffered queries at the same time? So, I need to use fetchAll or have

```
setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);
```

and also use closeCursor(). What I don't grasp yes is how to use allt of this to make it work.

This is my config file:

```
try {


    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=xx.xxx.xxx.xx; dbname=xxxxxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxxxx');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);
} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();

    die();

}
```

The page where I want my queries, I have not attempted to put out the result of my second query here, but the current code is:

```
 <?php
//including the database connection file
//include_once("config_local.php");
include_once("config.php");

session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['email']))
{
 header("location:index.php");
}

echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['name']; 



$result = $pdo->query("call aeroplane");
$result->closeCursor();
$result1 = $pdo->query("select * from plane_maker");
$result1->closeCursor();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Aeroplanes</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<section class="grid-1">
  <div class="item-1">1</div>

  <div class="item-2">
    <div class="item-5">
    <a href="add_form.php">Add New Aeroplane</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp;
        <a href="aeroplane_maker.php">Add New aeroplane maker</a>
        <br/><br/>

    <table width='80%' border=0>

    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
        <td>Maker Name</td>
        <td>Aeroplane</td>
        <td>Top speed</td>
        <td>Range</td>
        <td>Update</td>
    </tr>
    <?php

    while($row = $result->fetchAll()) {         
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['planeMakerName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['aeroplaneName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['aeroplaneTopSpeed']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['aeroplaneRange']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$row[aeroplaneID]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$row[aeroplaneID]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";        
    }

    ?>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="item-6">6</div>
    <div class="item-7">7</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item-4">4</div>
</section>
    </body>
</html>
```

-thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is not a real one. Which makes the code and the error unrelated to each other, which, in turn, makes it impossible to answer.

**You should always post the exact code that caused the error.**

Anyway, to make your code work you should fetch your data *before* closing the cursor. Because after closing there *obviously* will be be no data to fetch.

```
$result = $pdo->query("call aeroplane")->fetchAll();
$result->closeCursor();
$result1 = $pdo->query("select * from plane_maker")->fetchAll();
```

The error has nothing to do with buffered queries but with [stored procedures' behavior](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call).